# Programmatically 'auto hide menubar' in El capitan

Tags: macos, menu-bar, plist

I really love the 'auto hide menubar' option in El Capitan, but sometimes I like it (private) sometimes I don't (work). Is there a way to show/hide it programmatically by changed it's value in a plist file? If so, in which plist file is that setting found? Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

A bit more details about the circumstances: I use applescripts or bash scripts a lot to automate certain mundane tasks, like opening all my professional applications when I arrive at work. Usually I even export an applescript as an application so I can run it with spotlight, thus by entering one simple command in spotlight, all the relevant apps open. I'd love to do be able to toggle the auto-hide feature like this. It doesn't matter that much to me if this is done via editing a plist file with bash commands or automating it in some way via applescript.

Comment: I think that Stack Overflow will be more appropriate for the programmatically side of your question.

Comment: As long as "programmatically" means AppleScript, shell scripts or similar methods, the question is totally on-topic on AD. Can you describe in more detail under which circumstances you want to show/hide the menu bar?

Comment: I'm also thinking this isn't a SO question. Much better to keep it here IMO.

Comment: @patrix I added more details about the circumstances for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can set the menubar to be hidden and unhidden using [defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html):

To hide:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar -bool true
```

To show:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain _HIHideMenuBar -bool false
```

Once run, logout and log back in. Alternatively, you can run the following command as the logged-in user to restart Finder and show the changes:

```
killall Finder
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job. Only downside is the logout/login part (killall Finder works fine, except when you have many apps open, they need to be closed one by one) but I can live with that.

Comment: Please know that after this setting is applied, to see the changes take effect in any application, **you must restart said application**.